# Serve pre-compressed html files using apache2, functionality equivalent to mod_gunzip

Tags: apache-2.2, compression, html

Is there a way to implement [mod_gunzip's](http://www.innerjoin.org/apache-compression/howto.html) functionality using apache filters?

Store gzipped files on the server, hand out compressed data to the browsers that can cope with it and uncompress it for browsers which cannot.

I'm thinking of moving my website to a different host, but they don't offer enough diskspace, so wondering if there's a way to reduce the size of the html files (in thousands) I have.

I found [this website](http://blog.samat.org/2005/10/06/trying_to_emulate_mod_gunzip_with_apache_2_filters) which talks about it, but the instructions in the comments aren't working for me.

**UPDATE:**

According to @U4iK_HaZe's reply, mod-deflate in inflate mode, should also do the job, what would the configuration look like for that?

Comment: Here's the regular stuff: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html. Okay here it is... looking about half way down the page, you can use indeed, and INFLATE filter. Output Decompression

The mod_deflate module also provides a filter for inflating/uncompressing a gzip compressed response body. In order to activate this feature you have to insert the INFLATE filter into the outputfilter chain using SetOutputFilter or AddOutputFilter, for example:


 <Location /dav-area>
 ProxyPass http://example.com/
 SetOutputFilter INFLATE
 </Location>

Comment: My apologies for the spacing. It's not supporting code in the comment box. But look on the site a little less than half way down. There's some code you can use.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you would want to do this but mod-deflate on inflate mode is a hell of a lot easier to implement. i cant give you a code at the moment because im not able to access my config but if you can wait till tomorrow i can help more.

EDIT: find a new webhost.

Comment: it'd be cool if you could give me the mod-deflate on inflate mode configuration

Comment: Be patient, I will help you as soon as I can.

Comment: Hm. One minute ago, this was downvoted once more. But the topic should have been closed. Not helping the fact that I can't ask questions here. I'm trying to be useful.

Comment: @U4iK_HaZe Why can't you ask questions here? I downvoted it becuase of the spam. This is not an appropriate place to sell your services. If you want to advertise here, you need to pay for it like all the rest of the advertisers do.

Comment: This is not my service. One of the other recent posts about wcwma or whatever, is NOT my service. Simply put, I'm not promoting anything anymore, thought they were free, I stopped. But now it seems as though all of you have grudges against me now? :) cheer up. Lately, I've been trying to be as helpful as possible. I don't get it. And for the "host it free for a month" is just courtesy. I was offering a helping hand to someone in need. EDIT: I can't ask questions because people who downvote so much (I went from 81 rep to 72 in one day, and suddenly it says "No longer accepting questions".)

Comment: @U4iK_HaZe We all understand you're trying to be helpful. Thank you! Just please try and maintain appropriate behavior. Don't submit clarifying questions as "answers". That's what comments are for. Don't try and sell your services (even for free), and before submitting an answer, make sure it's fully applicable to the technology in question (for instance IIS vs. Apache).

Comment: Okay, so what do you suppose I do then? Keep posting answers to people and still be unable to ask any of my own questions, or just leave? I like this place a lot, it's one of a kind.

Comment: If you have clarifying questions, then post them as comments on the original question. We don't want you to leave! Just trying to help you understand how things work here...

Comment: Apart from clarifying questions it denies me the right to use the Ask Question button. "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to Ask Questions. I'd post something over on Serverfault Meta to see what's going on.

Comment: @U4ik - did you click that link in the message you mentioned? I don't know why the guys at Stack Exchange insist on making it a stupid URL shortner link, but the full link is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998

Comment: @Mark - Yes, I read it. It's seemingly impossible from herein to obtain my asker's permit again. I really hate to hijack the thread but I can't really do anything else. I am not going to make a new account. I don't want to cheat the system. I do though, feel helpless in terms of this site now. My reputation is 67 here. You need 20 to chat. I've never been able to chat. Maybe meta needs a rep of 20. I don't really know what to do.

Comment: @U4ik - meta has no restrictions on asking, so feel free to raise concerns there.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I'll see what I can do over there. Have a nice evening.